# Limits of trigonometric functions as $x$ approaches to a constant $a$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

$$\lim_{x \to a} \sin{x} = ?$$

$$\lim_{x \to a} \cos{x} = ?$$

What are some ways of computing these limits? I'd appreciate if you could post different methods as well.

Comment: Prove that the functions are continuous at $a$, then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=a$ follows.

Comment: How exactly do you define the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust please excuse me for the late reply. I prefer to define sin and cos using a unit circle.

Comment: Yes but what formalism do you use ? Geometry or calculus ?

Answer (score 2):

Both of the given functions are everywhere continuous. For every continuous function, we have $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = f(a)$$

Comment: At least in my courses we first prove the above limits, and deduce continuity of (co)sine as a consequence. How did *you* prove continuity of these functions?

Comment: Given the way OP asked his question, it'd seem like he was more interested in the computation of the limits, not the proof of them. Seeing as he accepted the answer, I take it that the asker did not want a formal proof. As to answer your question, I would've played around with the formal definition of the limit. I may update my answer.

Comment: A fair point, Andrew.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen how would you prove the limits? I understand your viewpont and am interested in a formal proof.

Comment: every point on the unit circle has both an abscissa and an ordinate defined. QED.

Comment: @gen That depends on how sine and cosine are defined in your book (which is why Yves asked about it). If by staring at the unit circle, then one way would be to first prove that we always have $|\sin x|\le |x|$ and use those nice trig formulas such as
$$\cos x- \cos a= -2\sin\frac{x+a}2\sin\frac{x-a}2,$$ where on the r.h.s. you estimate one factor using the earlier inequality, and the other as $|\sin\alpha|\le1$.

If, instead, (co)sine were defined using power series, then you get continuity from the general theory of power series.

Comment: @gen I believe, as Jyrki suggested, that power series is the way to go. I assume you are a student early in your mathematical career, and you will probably find power series to be far more intuitive and fruitful. Trigonometric identities are, of course, clever, but it is often better to be conceptual rather than technical early on. (This comment is based on my personal experience, this may greatly vary from student to student.)

Comment: @JohnJoy Could you please detail your proof? What does it actually prove? :S

Comment: @gen because an arbitrary point on a circle has coordinates $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ and a circle is defined as the set of points equidistant from the center (implying that a circle is a continuous curve) it follows that both sine and cosine are continuous as well.

Comment: @JohnJoy I'm sorry but I can't see this either. Your proof relies on that the circle is continuous but you don't prove it. It's like proving that Riemann's (Thomae's) function is continuous because for every $x\in D_f$ there is f(x)

Comment: @gen you're right. I don't prove it because the proof is trivial.

consider a unit circle centered about the origin. For any $x$ where $-1\le x\le 1$ there exists 2 values for y ($\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$). Now consider
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\lim_{h\to0}\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}&=&\sqrt{\lim_{h\to0}1-(x+h)^2}\\
&=&\sqrt{1-\lim_{h\to0}(x+h)^2}\\
&=&\sqrt{1-\lim_{h\to0}(x^2+2hx+h^2)}\\
&=&\sqrt{1-(x^2+\lim_{h\to0}2hx+\lim_{h\to0}h^2)}\\
&=&\sqrt{1-x^2}\\
\end{array}$$
We can also say, without a loss of generality, that
$$\lim_{h\to0}-\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
This shows that a circle is continuous.

Comment: @JohnJoy Thank you. I really liked your approach, but wanted to see its underpinnings.